# Profiling Python with Nvidia NSight

Tags: python, nsight

Does anyone know how to profile Python scripts with NVIDIA Nsight Systems?

I'm not sure what I would put in the Target Application field. I tried putting in the Spyder IDE (from Anaconda) and then executing my Python script from there, but I can't seem to import Tensorflow when I do that.

As soon as I import Tensorflow and use it, it tells me `"no such module"`. It seems that the Spyder IDE that I open from NSight Systems is different from the one when I open it normally (without Nsight).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this in windows using the answer from [nvidia forum](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/nsight-systems-cli-nsys-exe-program-not-found/168352):
So basically you should use a proper python environment and use the complete python directory like:

```
nsys profile C:\Users\beru\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe demo.py
```

By the way, this answer also helps me to know what to do for profiling python code using nsight system on win. I strongly recommend anyone puzzled by this read it.